# Counting how many layers exist at a specific position on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page is running a touchmove event which captures the position of the user's finger on the screen via:

```
xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
yPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
```

The page has many layers (created with position:absolute divs) and at this point, I want to calculte how many such layers exist below the user's current position on the screen.

The only method I can think of is to have an array of all the layers' positions and loop through that. However that seems rather processor intensive when there may be hundreds of layers on screen at once.

Is there a simple way in js or JQuery to count the items that exist in a position, or a better practise way to do it than my array suggestion.

Comment: document.elementFromPoint() gives you top layer element but I don't think there is a simple way to go through layers below it. That being said one idea would be instantaneously hide that and keep doing same until you get to body

Comment: Might give that a try - if it doesn't cause a flicker, then that seems simpler.

Comment: Be curious what you find out trying it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such way. My approach would be to give all layers a certain class, select them all and iterate through them. Depending on what you are trying to achieve with this and how often you'll have to perform this calculation, it may be possible to use caching and approximation (e.g. not checking a certain pixel but an area of x^2 pixels and caching the result, etc) to make things run faster.

That being said, I encourage you to first try the solution that you've thought of and see how fast it actually runs. Browsers are pretty fast for such standard operations (think layer drag & drop with boundary checks), so I'm pretty confident that it won't be as slow as you think it will be :)